# Restore file that was overriden with rsync

Tags: data-recovery, rsync, restore

I accidentaly overrode a file while transfering some data with `rsync -avz`.

Is is possible to restore it? I looked at [Photorec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) but it seems to be looking through the whole drive, which in my case is 1 TB and according to the latest estimate will take over 13hours (and this is constantly increasing) to just scan and I have no idea what I will be presented with afterwards.

Comment: I saw this but have never used it might help: https://gist.github.com/bonyiii/1471379

Comment: Doestn't seem to work. It doesn't show me any files. I even tried a test where I created a file and deleted it or overwrote it and used debugfs immediately afterwards - nothing.